# How can we set the env variable of pre-existing composer env using terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create a composer environment using terraform. I want to use the same bucket name created by the env, in my DAG for which I am trying to set it as env variable. Since the bucket name is known after the composer env is created, how can I set the env variable for the existing composer env using terraform. I am new to terraform script, your approaches would be of great help!

Comment: Are there any errors? If so, please add them to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the same bucket name used by `Composer` in the `DAG` code, I think you can directly use a [predefined env variable](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/set-environment-variables) and no need to set an extra env variable.

You have the following env variable : `GCS_BUCKET`

You can retrieve it in the `DAG` `Python` code :

```py
COMPOSER_GCS_BUCKET = os.getenv("GCS_BUCKET")
```

Comment: You're welcome, if this helped to solve your issue, can you mark it as solved ?